# parsexact increasing hours by 2

Tags: powershell

I am trying to parse a string and add 5 minutes in it and again store it in a string variable. For no apparent reason, parseexact is increasing by 2 hours in the timestamp.

To exclude all other possible issues, I simply tried to store current time in a string variable and then parse it using parseexact. Problem is still the same:

```
$timestamp = (Get-date).tostring('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ')

$newtime = [datetime]::parseexact($timestamp,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ',$null)



$timestamp = 2019-09-01T21:58:19.009Z

$newtime =  Sunday, September 1, 2019 11:58:19 PM (there is 2 hours difference in this output and what I expect)
```

Comment: for me, the time difference is 5 hours. that is the time zone offset for US-Central, so i suspect that there is a glitch in how the `Z` is being read.. if i remove the from the patterns, i get the correct time info.

Comment: As @Lee_Dailey says. You can also add `.ToUniversalTime()` like `$newtime = [datetime]::ParseExact($timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ', $null).ToUniversalTime()`. ($newtime will then of course also be UNC time)

Comment: .._UNC time_ should of course be `UTC time`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- On **TO-string formatting** of a `[datetime]` instance with `.ToString()`, the **trailing `Z`** in format string in `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ` is **treated as a *literal***.

  - That is, specifying `Z` will *not* automatically convert the *local* `[datetime]` instance returned by `Get-Date` to UTC; instead, the formatted *local* time is simply followed by letter `Z`.
- On **FROM-string parsing** into a `[datetime]` instance with `.ParseExact()`, the **trailing `Z` *is* interpreted as *denoting UTC***.

---

**Therefore, your `$timestamp` string represents a *local* time that is *mislabeled as UTC*** due to the trailing `Z`, and that is why parsing that string into `$newtime` ends up as a *different* - also local - time; *how* different depends on your local time zone's offset from UTC.

To correct the problem you have two options:

- **Explicitly *convert to UTC* first**:

  - `(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffK')`
  - Example output:

    - `2019-09-02T04:54:43.707Z`
- Represent `$timestamp` as a *local time* and  *include the UTC offset*:

  - `(Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffK')`
  - For instance, in the US EDT time zone the equivalent of the above UTC time stamp is (note the trailing `-04:00` UTC offset):

    - `2019-09-02T00:54:43.707-04:00`

Note how [custom format specifier `K`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#KSpecifier) was used in both commands: `K` expands to either the UTC offset (e.g., `-04:00`) or to `Z`, depending on whether the input time stamp is *local* (`.Kind` is `DateTimeKind.Local`) or in *UTC* (`.Kind` is `DateTimeKind.Utc`).

---

As stated, `$newtime` will contain a *local* time stamp, converted from UTC time stamp represented by the string; to get its UTC equivalent, simply call `.ToUniversalTime()` (again).

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @Manishraghav.